# Django - How to refer to a model's primary key

Tags: django, pandas, bokeh

Model: (notice kundenr set as primary key) (means customer number in Norwegian)

```
class Kunde(models.Model):
avd = [('610','610'), ('615', '615'), ('620', '620'), ('625', '625'), ('630', '630'),('635', '635'),('640', '640'),('645', '645'), ('650', '650'), ('655', '655')]

avdeling = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=avd)
selskap = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
orgnr = models.CharField('Organisasjonsnummer', max_length=11)
kundenr = models.CharField('Kundenummer', max_length=15, unique=True, primary_key=True)
gatenavn = models.CharField(max_length=50,)
postnr = models.CharField('Postnummer', max_length=4)
poststed = models.CharField(max_length=30)
kommune = models.CharField(max_length=30)
kontaktperson = models.CharField(max_length=50)
tlf_kontor = models.CharField("Telefon kontor", max_length=12)
tlf_mobil = models.CharField("Telefon mobil", max_length=12)
epostadresse = models.EmailField()
timestamp = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)


def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("kunder:detaljer", kwargs={"id": self.kundenr})

def __str__(self):
    return self.selskap

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['selskap']
```

View

```
def kunde_detail(request, kundenr):
template = 'kunder/detaljer.html'
instance = get_object_or_404(Kunde, kundenr=kundenr) 

# pandas code removed as it was quite long

utvalgt_kunde = 727636   # this should refer to the chosen Kunde.kundenr


# more pandas code removed

context = {
    "utvalgt_kunde": instance.kundenr,
    "selskap": instance.selskap, 
    "instance": instance, 
    "kunde_script": script,
    "kunde_div": div
}
return render(request, template, context)
```

In the views function I need 'utvalgt kunde'  =  to the 'kundenr' since the graph needs to be dynamic.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrXSq.png) is a screenshot of the list of customers. When I click on a customer name I get directed to the customer details page. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6knY.png) is a screenshot of my details page. In this example I have hardcoded the 'kundenr' but of course this will just render the same graph regardless of which customer is chosen.

I am aware that this may not be as clear as it should be, and if so, feel free to ask me to revise the question if needed. If my chosen method is the wrong way to approach this I welcome any suggestions that can point me in the rigth direction.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand at all. The `kundenr` is already being passed into the view, you already have it in the variable by that exact name; why do you need to get it back from the instance? And even if you did, why would doing so be different from getting any other value such as `selskap`?

Comment: you are passing kundenr in the view, so why not utvalgt_kunde = kundenr like this? this will give you the id chosen by user or what does kundenr contains?

Comment: Ok, I feel sligthly dumb right now :)  You guys are right. I changed it to utvalgt_kunde = int(kundenr)   and that worked. Thank you both.